# Multiindex groupby python

Tags: python, indexing, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I have a Multiindex dataframe like this after groupby and sort value descending usage

```
peak = df.groupby(["month_year"]).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(["Usage"], ascending = False)
```

```html
                  DateTime        Usage
month_year        
2012-01   2055 2012-01-22 10:00:00 55 
          351 2012-01-04 16:00:00 52 
         .....
2012-12  34545 2012-12-25 20:30:00 22
         34505 2012-12-25 10:30:00 21
```

How can I only keep just the index of first row of each month_year? In other word, I only want to keep '2055' and '34545'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use reset_index and groupby:

```
df1.reset_index(level=1).groupby('month_year').first()
```

Output:

```
            level_1             DateTime  Usage
month_year                                     
2012-01        2055  2012-01-22 10:00:00     55
2012-12       34545  2012-12-25 20:30:00     22
```